# unexpected compilation error when passing by reference anonymous instance

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a struct :

```
struct structazauras
{ 
string bla;
}
```

And some function (in my case this function is actually a constructor of some class but I don't think this is the issue):

```
void myfunc(structazauras& mystruct) { }
```

then some where i call myfunc :

```
..
myfunc(structazauras());
..
```

I get an error:

```
no matching function for call to myfunc(structazauras) candidates are myfunc(structazauras&)
```

If I change the code to :

```
structazauras tmp;
myfunc(tmp);
```

It will work fine.

I feel that he (the compiler) has a problem passing a reference to the anonymous instance if `structazauras`, but why ? the anonymous instance exist on the stack of the calling function.

Comment: `myfunc(structazaourous());` requires a `const structazaourous&` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference. Mark your reference as `const` and it will work.

Also, you are using a standard C++ keyword (`struct`) in the definition

```
void myfunc(structazauras& struct) { }
```

Change the name to something else. Or maybe you meant

```
void myfunc(struct structazauras&) { }
```

but the additional `struct` is superfluous in C++.

Comment: why i can't bind temporary to non-const reference ? what is the difference between the life expectancy of tmp instance vs the anonymous instance, they both live on the stack, aren't they ?

Comment: @OopsUser I guess the C++ standard didn't want to keep alive temp objects while allowing you to further modify them. Not absolutely sure that this is the reason, but it makes some sense.

Comment: @OopsUser: To avoid confusion, for example if a type conversion causes the reference to bind to a temporary, when you expect it to modify an existing variable. See the dupe for full details.